# Getting TypeError in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new in node js. I am getting a typeerror while using .get function. The error is

> TypeError: item.get is not a function

Code --

```js
query.lean().exec(function (err, data)
{
  JSON.stringify(data);
  callback(null,data,count);
});

function(data,count,callback)
{
  //...some code
  callback(null,[count,data]);
}

function(docs, callback){
  console.log(docs[1]);

  async.each(docs[1],function(item,cb) {
    if (typeof(item.video.path)!="undefined") {
      item.players.cover = config.general+ item.video.path;
    }
  });
}
```

I did `console.log(docs[1])` and the `video.path` exist within the json object.Before using lean() this set and get was working but not now.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `item`?  Why do you think it has a `.get()` method?

Comment: item is the json object. In that case it could be item.video.path

Comment: JSON is a pure text format used for interchange of data.  I presume this is actually a Javascript object.  If so, it probably doesn't have a `.get()` or `.set()` method as those are not standard parts of Javascript objects.  I would suggest that you edit your question to show us several things: 1) What exactly is `item`?  2) What exactly are you trying to accomplish with that object?  If it's an ordinary object and you just want to add a property if it isn't already there, then just say that in your question.

Comment: I will do it now.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have updated the post.

Comment: Please provide a link to the `lean` library you're using so we can see what it is.  Also, why are you doing `JSON.stringify(data)` on the results of your query?  And, why does the first callback show `callback(null, data, count)`, but the next function (which I presume is what it is calling) is `function(data, count, callback)`.  They don't appear to match.

Comment: Also, I think we need to see your real code here, not the pseudo code you have in your question now.  For example, you show tow functions that have no name on them so we have no idea how they are called or what is calling what.

Comment: Sorry yes I know it's not the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `item` is an object de-serialised from JSON, then there's no way it has **any** methods or functions.

I suspect you just want to set a property on the object. Something like

```
if (typeof item.video.path !== 'undefined') {
  // ensure item.players is an object first
  item.players = item.players || {}

  // now set the value
  item.players.cover = config.general + item.video.path
}
```

Comment: Yes I need to set a property on the object. I am using mongoose lean option which returns plain javascript object and then I changed that in json using JSON.stringify and then I am running async.each function. Before using lean option it was working.

Comment: When I do item.players.cover = config.general + item.video.path it says TypeError: Cannot read property 'cover' of undefined because cover is not there. I need to create it dynamically.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra that doesn't make any sense as nothing in this code is trying to **read** `item.players.cover`

Comment: Trying to set the value in cover?

Comment: Sorry the error msg is `TypeError: Cannot set property 'cover' of undefined
`

Comment: And that's **exactly** why my code has `item.players = item.players || {}`. Does **your code** have that?

Comment: Working now but do you think declaring this --  `item.players = item.players || {}` inside the loop is a good idea.

Comment: Can't see why not. Where else are you going to do it?

Comment: That's the only place though.  But anyways thanks for your help and I think I need to understand more about the returning resultset type from lean(). It says its plain javascript not json.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra _"JSON"_ is a string format. It may be parsed into a plain JavaScript object. Plain JavaScript objects may have properties and methods / functions but JSON strings can only specify properties. Therefore, your _parsed_ objects will not have any functions